# Hello World Java Applet Won't display in Firefox for Ubuntu

Tags: java, browser, applet

Hi guys I'm having some trouble running my first applet on Java.  I'm pretty new to Ubuntu but here's what I have so far....
For my HelloWorldApplet.java file:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class HelloWorldApplet extends java.applet.Applet{

public void paint(Graphics g) {

    g.drawString("Hello World!",5,25);
}



}
```

Then I compiled it into a HelloWorldApplet.class file.  Here is my html code:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> Hello to Everyone!</TITLE>
</HEAD> <BODY>
<body bgcolor = red>
<P> My Java applet says:
<APPLET CODE="HelloWorldApplet.class" WIDTH=150 HEIGHT=25>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

When I try to open it with mozilla firefox, it doesn't display the hello world message it only has "My Java applet says:"  With the red background.

I've also ran this java code as a application and it works fine.  When I try to run it using appletviewer it works about half the time... Sometime I would see the applet window with the text and sometimes nothings happen and I don't even get an error sign, it's  so strange.
Can anyone please give me some ideas for why I can't get the applet to work?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Try installing icedtea-plugin and restarting the browser.

```
sudo apt-get install icedtea-plugin
```

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply bgamlath, I've followed your instructions and rebooted my computer as well, unfortunately it still didn't work.  Btw has anyone else ran into the same problem as me where sometimes the appletviewer works and sometimes it just acted like i never called it in the terminal and nothing happens, but theres no error and it looks like termninal is perfectly fine?

Comment: In my case, it worked. I installed IcedTea Java Browser Pluging from Ubuntu software center. Now it's shown as a plugin in Firefox. When I deactivated it, I got the same result you described.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to identify the source of your problem...

- maybe it's because you don't guarantee a redraw on start()?
- maybe it's because your screen isn't properly drawn (super.paint)?
- maybe your colors are not set properly?

try some of those tweak...

```
public class YourApplet extends JApplet{
    public YourApplet() throws HeadlessException {

    @Override
    public void init() {
        super.init();
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }
    @Override
    public void start() {
        super.start();
        repaint();
    }
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString("Hello World!",5,25);
    }

}
```